# Why does this APT package have a four-part version number, with a dash?

Tags: apt

For example, why is the package named `linux-headers-3.2.0-45` when actually it represents `3.2.45`?

Answer (score 1):

In case of the linux kernel first try:

```
$ uname -r
```

This shows you the current version of the linux kernel you are currently running. There you will see a version like the version of the package. But you are right, that this is not the version of the kernel you can find on kernel.org. The number that is following the dash represents the kernel revision of your current Ubuntu.

Every time when there is a bug or security issue fixed the number following the dash will increased.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand why the apt package has a four-part number, given that the true version number has three parts.

Comment: Is have a four part number! But the fourth is a sub-version that is  not always mentioned. But as you can see in uname -r that the sub-version is present on your system, not only in the apt-package.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine it's because the `.0` part technically counts for nothing as it's a zero. `3.2.45` would be identical to `3.2.0-45`. As for the dash, that typically symbolizes a revision number (in my experience). 
`3.2.0-45` would be:

Linux kernel major version 3, minor version 2, patch 0, revision 45

[source](http://semver.org/)